# Cron job fails to execute python script that writes to text file

Tags: python-3.x, cron, writetofile

I need to run a python script on a remote server (I'm not the owner of this server, so I cannot check `var/log/syslog`).  The script is put in a folder with other files that the scripts depends on to be able to run.  The script will write out a text files, the information being written includes runtime of the script.

If I executed the script manually, it will write text file with all correct information.  However, when I set a test cron job to make sure my script run and the output file looks like what I'd like, the output file has only one line that includes a very small float which I assume to be the runtime of the script.  The default python version of the server is python 2.7.  However, my script need python3 to run.  Below is the crontab command that I use

```
# crontab command
# the time is just an example
23 23 13 4 6 /usr/bin/python3 /home/user_name/path/to/file.py
```

I have tried using just `python3 files.py` and `python3.5 files.py`, same result for all cases.

All the files in the folder I tried to run my scripts and my script itself is `chmod 707`

Also, side question, I'm sharing this server with other people; however, I don't want them to be able to open my files, what chmod should I set my files and folder to so that cron would still be able to execute my files and people won't be able to view it (beside the owner of the server)

Comment: What happens if you run `/usr/bin/python3 /home/user_name/path/to/file.py` after ssh'ing in?

Comment: @HeathRaftery it wrote out the text file as I wanted

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 707` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network. (Points for originality, though; usually people who don't know what they are doing blindly use  `chmod 777`.)

Answer (score 0):

First, permissions:

- Every user has a crontab, and the entries in a user's crontab run as that user.
- The three numbers in a files permission are user, group and other.
- Typically a user has their own group, and they are the only member of it.

So that means if you want to keep your stuff to your self, only grant permissions to your user (and optionally, your group, which is the same thing if you're the only member). Your crontab will have no trouble accessing anything your user can access.

Thus, give all the relevant directories and all the text files ownership of `user_name:user_name` and permissions of `660` (only you can read and write to them). Give all the executable files the same ownership but permissions of `770` (so you can also execute them).

Then, if you have ssh access, just execute `/usr/bin/python3 /home/user_name/path/to/file.py` from the command line to see where it's falling over. Assuming you don't have ssh access, then you need to capture the output from the crontab execution. Use this crontab line:

```
23 23 13 4 6 /usr/bin/python3 /home/user_name/path/to/file.py > /home/user_name/output.txt 2>&1
```

That will redirect all STDERR to STDOUT (the `2>&1` bit) and redirect STDOUT to output.txt (the `>` bit).

Let that run and check the contents of output.txt. I'm guessing you'll find Python had trouble getting access to something and bombed out before writing much to the file.

Comment: I do have ssh access.  I tried what you suggested, first run the `/usr/bin/python3 /home/user_name/path/to/file.py`.  It wrote out the text file as I wanted.  I tried the second suggestion of redirecting all STDERR to STDOUT, it didn't write to the `output.txt` file at all (file is created but it is empty), while the file that I want still had the same line including small float.  When I tried to do the redirecting manually, I got the two files with content exactly as expected

Comment: Well that's strange! I'd try creating a simpler `file.py`, trying that and building up from there.

Comment: Whether each user gets a group of their own is system-dependent. Many modern Linux distros are set up this way now, but many older true Unixes were not.